# Prestashop 1.7 friendly URL

Tags: url, prestashop-1.7

I'm having troubles with Prestashop friendly URLs. They are working for products or categories, but not for newproducts and pricesdrop.

For example, if I go to "Shop Parameters" -> "SEO & URLS" and create a new "pricesdrop" from the pagename's dropdown and a Rewritten url of "rebajas", the links pointing to that page don't change, they are like:

index.php?controller=prices-drop

If I manually enter /rebajas, I got redirected to the non pretty url. I've already tried clearing the cache and regenerate .htaccess with the same result.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Traffic & SEO > SEO & URLs (tab)` there is already page with page with **Page Title** named **Prices drop**; just edit it and give your choice of friendly URL `rebajas`. No need to create new page for prices drop.

Now open your shop with `{SHOP_URL}/rebajas`; you will see price drop page working fine. Attaching image for your reference.

[image]

Hope it will help you!